# Edit sessions file to update values

Tags: php, session, session-variables

i am questionning myself about the fact to edit php session files(with provided PHP tools like session_dedode and so on).

The idea is : i have a datanase with users informations like name,access rights,group membership. Those precious data are stored into $SESSION when user connects. When an admin edit some data into db, i want those data to be updated in the user session data as soon as possible (currently those infos are enumerated at user logon).

Is this a good way to directly loop into session files and replace the outdated data ? I thought about perf issues if there are many session files.  <strike>And another related question is is there a way to recover the session file of a current $SESSION</strike> . I found it rihght now it is just the concatenation of "sess_$PHPSESSID"

Right now i was thinking about adding some user related fields into db like lastConfigReadTime and compare it with some already existing field lastEditTimestamp and update session data accordingly.

How you guys handle this kind of scenario ? What kind of process are you using ? Do you have any recommendations ?

Thanks for you time.

BR.